# MongoDB: How to Delete Entry If a Field Contains an Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a javascript app that is uploading data to a MongoDB. I had a bug in my code which caused database entries to contain all previous entries plus the new one.

For Example I have this invalid entry:

```
"created":["4/6/2018 10:45:49 AM","4/6/2018 10:51:07 AM","4/6/2018 10:55:16 AM","4/6/2018 10:56:41 AM"]
```

I would like to go through the database entries and remove all entries where the filed contains an array. I want to remove the entire entry, not just the field as any entry with more than one value is invalid.

Keep this:

```
{"created":"4/6/2018 10:45:49 AM"}
```

Remove this:

```
{"created":["4/6/2018 10:45:49 AM","4/6/2018 10:51:07 AM","4/6/2018 10:55:16 AM","4/6/2018 10:56:41 AM"]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
db.col.deleteMany({ created: { $type: 4 } })
```

[$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) is an operator which examines the type of particular field. Value 4 represents an array.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)